# Jabber: Logging user status changes

Tags: jabber

Does anyone know of a Jabber client that will allow you to log the times that users in your contact list change their status, and what those status changes are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/). Check `Tools` > `System Log`. It does it for all the account types, not just Jabber.

Comment: Will give that a go. Ta